# ¿Como muestro la cantidad de columnas de cada tabla de mi base de datos MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, tablas

Tengo una base de datos donde quiero mostrar el nombre de cada tabla y su cantidad de columnas. Claro está filtrar por la cantidad de columnas que tienen las tablas.

Estas son mis tablas de mi base de datos "turismodb":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso ésta sentencia para mostrar todas las tablas que tengo:

```sql
/*Muestra todas las tablas de la db*/
SELECT table_name AS nombre
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'turismodb';
```

[image: lista de tablas de la db]

Y ésta para mostrar una tabla y su cantidad de campos:

```sql
/*Muestra cantidad de columna de una tabla*/
SELECT TABLE_NAME, count( COLUMN_NAME )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'lugares'
AND table_schema = 'turismodb';
```

[image: la tabla y su cantidad de campos]

¿Como hago para mostrar dos columnas con (nombre de tabla) y (cantidad de campos) de todas las tablas de mi base de datos?

[image: tabla final]

Comment: Quita el `table_name = 'tb_persona' AND`, creo que eso bastará.

Comment: Hola Antonio, si lo probé de la manera que mencionas pero me sale solo una tabla con la cantidad total de campos de todas mis tablas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con este query que es una muy simple modificacion de tu ultimo query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, count( COLUMN_NAME )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'turismodb' group by table_name;
```

espero sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: Emiliano, capo, gracias, es lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta, añado para los interesados, como filtrar las tablas por cantidad de columnas, por ejemplo seleccionar las tablas que solo tengan 2 columnas:

```sql
SELECT total.NOMBRE as nombre_tabla, total.COLUMNAS as cantidad_campos FROM
(SELECT TABLE_NAME AS NOMBRE, count( COLUMN_NAME ) as COLUMNAS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'turismodb' group by table_name) AS total WHERE total.COLUMNAS = 2;
```